# How to expose implementation files for certain files inside an iOS framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, ios-frameworks

I'm currently following [this guide](http://rayvinly.com/how-to-build-a-truly-universal-framework-for-ios-and-mac-with-just-a-single-codebase/) to create an iOS framework to reuse among my projects. But I encounter a bit of a problem, I hope someone can help me out.

Here is the short version of my question: is there any way that I can expose certain *implementation files* from the framework to allow the containing project to overwrite/extend it while exposing only *header files* for the rest of the framework?

Here are some more details of what I'm trying to achieve.

Inside my framework, I have 2 classes, one extends another:

**FrameworkClassA : FrameworkClassB**

Inside the project that uses this framework, I want to extend these 2 classes to add custom methods specific to that project. So I did:

**ProjectClassA : FrameworkClassA
ProjectClassB : FrameworkClassB**

This works fine. However, the problem is, at the same time, I also want:

**ProjectClassA : ProjectClassB**

Basically, think of it as B is always higher than A, any method available in B needs to be also available in A.

As far as I know, multiple inheritance in Objective C is not possible. There are workarounds using class composition but I'm not very familiar with it and it seems a bit complex for what I want to do here.

So I have a bit of an "idea", but not sure how to do it. I'm thinking to have this chain of inheritance inside the framework:

**SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassA : FrameworkClassA : SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassB : FrameworkClassB**

SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassA & SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassB implementation files will be mostly empty inside the framework. I then expose only *header files* for all the files inside the framework (including FrameworkClassA & FrameworkClassB) but make SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassA & SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassB *implementation files* visible and editable.

Then inside the project that uses the framework, I will not create new classes but instead put my custom codes *inside* SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassA & SAMPLE_PROJECT_ClassB and everything will follow the inheritance hierarchy that I want.

Is this possible? Or what is the best way to achieve something like this? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE 1: Attached diagram**

Please find the diagram of what how the classes are related here:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/20st6ow.jpg

(sorry, not having enough reputation to upload an image. Maybe someone can vote this question up to help me out in the future? :-P)

In that diagram:

- "F" is framework and "P" is project.
- Black Arrow is inheritance
- Blue Arrow is "potential" inheritance between P classes and F classes.

Eventually, I want to be able to access **FHelperA**, **FHelperB** and **openMenu** from **PTableViewController**.

Comment: Would your framework classes basically just have empty implementations? If so, you could use a protocol instead

Comment: @michaels, **FrameworkClassA** and **FrameworkClassB** will have lots of implementations in them and also have instance variables so I can't go with protocol or categories. Regarding the SAMPLE_PROJECT classes, they will contain custom project codes so they also have to be physical classes in order to be part of the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance, so **ProjectClassA** can't inherit from both **FrameworkClassA** and **ProjectClassB**.

Some ideas:

- Depending on how you would like to design your framework you may want to look into class clusters, where you can have one interface and multiple implementations. This is a good place to start [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)
- You can have a 3 classes instead of 2, one base class with all the shared methods and your A and B for your separate ones.
- Another idea would be to use categories to extend the functionality, i.e. the A classes could extend the B classes, though you A classes won't inherit from each other.

Also consider drawing the graph of how you would like you classes in your frameworks to related to each other as this will help a lot to think of the design.

Comment: Class cluster looks interesting. Will definitely check it out. The main problem that I'm facing is the fact that a class inside my Framework cannot extend another class inside or editable by my Project as in the case of **FrameworkClassA** needed to extend **ProjectClassB**. With class cluster, I assume one of the private classes will be from the Framework and the other is from my Project? If so, can the Project one extends the Framework one?

Comment: I have updated my post to attach a diagram. I hope this will make it a bit clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Having thought about this for a while I can't think of a good solution that would work with the design you provide in your diagram, so you may want to reconsider the architecture. Having said that I'm not an expert in Objective-C, so there are possibly things I'm missing.

Comment: No worries. Thanks a lot for your help. One way to think about this problem is to imagine that you want to extend UITableView and UIScrollView at the same time (let's say category is not an option because you need instance variable). How can you do that while having your new UITableView class also inherit the new codes inside your new UIScrollView class.

Comment: Having said that, I found a workaround which involes some code duplication, not ideal, but good enough for me for now. The above comment is more like food for thoughts :-)